# Understanding step in a calculation. Why is $||e||^2_E\leq 2 ||e||_E\cdot||u-v||_E$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I'm trying to enderstand the equations below for an estimate of the a-priori error in the energy norm. My professor writes in his notes that

> \begin{align} ||e||_E^2 &= \int_0^1e'(u-v)'+2xe'(u-v)+2e(u-v) \ dx \\
>  &\leq 2||e'||\cdot||u-v||_E+2||e||\cdot ||u-v|| \\ &\leq 2||e||_E\cdot
>  ||u-v||_E \end{align}
>
> and derive the a priori error estimate
>
> $$||e||_E\leq (1+\alpha)||u-v||_E , \quad \forall v\in V_h.$$

Questions:

**1)** What happens to the $x$ in the integrand?

**2)** Why do only some of the norms get an $E$ as an index and not all of them?

**3)** In the second $\rightarrow$ third step, he just removes the $2||e'||\cdot ||u-v||_E$ I assume? If that's the case, then we should only have been left with $2||e||\cdot |||u-v||$, why indexing the norms with $E$'s? I'm starting to think that $||.||=||.||_E$ and that he just forgot to add them to all.

**4)** Where does $\alpha$ come from? Says nothing anywhere about the nature of $\alpha$ for this problem.